# Crossposting from WP to Blogger with comments

Tags: comments, posts

I know that there is a way to crosspost from WP to Blogger but I am curious if there is a way to essentially mirror WP blog on Blogger completely, in other words crosspost both posts and comments?

Comment: Is there some kind of preference? Posts, your users and your comments or both?

Comment: Just curious why you want this?  Are you familiar with the Google duplicate content penalty? http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/demystifying-duplicate-content-penalty.html

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Good point! My client is trying to have a cheap failover mechanism, in case WP blog fails for a fast switchover to Blogger... :(

Comment: @hakre Preferably both :)

Comment: The hard part will be commenting as someone else. If you still want to know how to achieve this on Blogger (not on WordPress), I think you should ask this on [the WebApps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), since the hard part is on the Blogger side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Alex:**

Your client wants to mirror on Blogger this *"In case WordPress fails?!?"* OMG!!!! Do they not understand how WordPress works?

Set him up a second WordPress site on a different web host or on WordPress.com! Don't put up with Blogger.

A simple solution would be to use [Windows Live Writer](http://windowslivewriter.spaces.live.com/) or [Qumana](http://www.qumana.com/) to write the posts and then just having them submit to both sites using those programs.

A programming solution would be to monitor RSS feeds on a psuedo-cron task and then import them with `wp_insert_post()`:

- [Import and Display RSS Feeds in WordPress](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/04/26/import-and-display-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/)
- [Pseudo Cron Jobs with WordPress](http://chipsandtv.com/articles/wordpress-pseudo-crons)
- [Function Reference/wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

But whatever you do get them to stick with WordPress on the multiple sites; doing anything else is madness!

Comment: +1000. Use the same platform for a "failover," just on a different host.

Comment: problem is the site that they running is pretty high traffic. Right now with all the optimizations installed it get's a dedicated server to load avg of 1-2 with peaks at 4-6(for dual core that's ok I guess). So having a failover will require similar box which is somewhat costly for their budget. But you're right anyway, your answer will help me to talk to them further and confirm that I am not crazy/lazy/not-experienced-enough :) we'll see how it goes. Thanks!